# angular material md-autocomplete remove md-floating-label attribute not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I have the following code when using the md-autocomplete directive in angular-material. I want to remove the md-floating-label entirely from the element if the acType != FORMULA:

html:

`ng-attr-md-floating-label="{{ autocompleteFloatingLabel }}"`

JS:

```
scope.autocompleteFloatingLabel = false;
if (scope.acType == Constants.Autocomplete.FORMULA) {
  scope.autocompleteFloatingLabel = 'Add a formula here ';
}
```

I have tried setting the autocompleteFloatingLabel to undefined instead of false I have also tried remove the brackets in the HTML template. Nothing seems to work. I know that the scope.acType is evaluating to the proper value, but md-floating-label seems to still be there when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

Give id to your autocomplete as 'autocomplete_id'

**JS:**

```
var elem=angular.element('#autocomplete_id');
elem.find('label').html('');
if (scope.acType == Constants.Autocomplete.FORMULA) {
    elem.find('label').html('Add a formula here');
}
```